# Reading From XML skipping first line?

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am reading from an XML file, and the reader not only seems to be skipping the first sub-element, but through debugging it's like it's not even there.

```
 While reader.Read

            Select Case reader.NodeType
                Case XmlNodeType.Comment

                Case XmlNodeType.Element


                    ElementNames.SetValue(reader.LocalName, ElementCount)
                    ElementText.SetValue(reader.ReadString, ElementCount)
                    ElementCount += 1
                    ReDim Preserve ElementNames(ElementCount)
                    ReDim Preserve ElementText(ElementCount)


            End Select
        End While
```

**EDIT 1:** I shuffled around the code inside `Case XmlNodeType.Element`, and while almost all of it works fine, as it is reading `<Obit>`it nears the end of that Case I just mentioned and immediate reads `<unique-id>`, so by the time it loops back to `While reader.Read`, it is actually reading the TEXT of `<unique-id>` which seems to mess it up. Then after that, everything proceeds normally. So now, I'm not sure how to get it to NOT do that. I can't just use `reader.Read` again, because that just pushes everything ahead. **END EDIT 1**

All of the above code works except for a first sub-element like this:

```
<Obit>
  <unique-id>1</unique-id> '(this line is skipped)
  <year-born>1907</year-born>
  <date-of-death>
    <day>03</day> '(this line is skipped)
    <month>04</month>
    <year>1947</year>
  </date-of-death>
  <obit-text>qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq</obit-text>
</Obit>
```

I indicated which lines are being skipped. Now if I instead, write an XML comment on the first line, the comment is skipped and I get all of the information.

Is there some finicky issue with the XMLReader, or first lines?
Like I said, when I debug it, I follow it through it shows that it is reading `<Obit>`on the `ElementNames.SetValue(reader.LocalName, ElementCount)`line in my Select statement. And it progresses to the next node, and seems to just skip it all together.

Is the fact that `<Obit>` does not have any text/string in it a possible point of failure? The `ElementText.SetValue(reader.ReadString, ElementCount)`line shows that nothing is being read from `<Obit>`, which I thought was fine as there are only sub-elements (child elements? Descendants? Not totally sure on proper terminology here).

Comment: What's the initial value of `ElementCount` and initial size of the arrays? How do you read the data from the arrays? The code reading the XML seems right, so the next possible issues would be that the data is not put in the right place in the arrays, or not read correctly from the arrays.

Comment: Before the reader even gets to the array. If I hover over `reader.`, it shows me the name of the element or it's text (in debug mode). It shows me `<Obit>`, tries to go to `<unique-id>` and doesn't. It skips to the line AFTER.   The initial value of ElementCount = 0 and my arrays start at 0, and if the reader reads an Element it ReDims and adds one more. But I can't see those being an issue since the reader doesn't even show it, before/while the current line is being read this happens. I can't even get the data.

Comment: I think that you need to check the names of the elements that you read. Now you are treating the first element as if it was a child element, so when you read the text node I think that it will skip until it finds one in the first child, and the next node that you read is the second child element.

Comment: Made changes to initial post****************

Answer (score 1):

Your problem appears to be that you're using `reader.ReadString`, which reads the next node as a string.  What you want is to `Read()` the text element and use `reader.Value`.  This highlights another problem in that it will read the line breaks if no text is there.  A simple conditional will take care of that:

```
While reader.Read

    Select Case reader.NodeType
        Case XmlNodeType.Comment

        Case XmlNodeType.Element


            ElementNames.SetValue(reader.LocalName, ElementCount)
            reader.Read()
            Dim textValue As String = reader.Value
            If textValue.StartsWith(vbLf) Then
                textValue = ""
            End If
            ElementText.SetValue(textValue, ElementCount)
            ElementCount += 1
            ReDim Preserve ElementNames(ElementCount)
            ReDim Preserve ElementText(ElementCount)
    End Select
End While
```

On a side note, using concurrent arrays can lead to many problems in a large project.  I would recommend a custom class or struct and create a list of those objects:

```
Class ElementValue
    Public Name As String = ""
    Public Text As String = ""
End Class

Dim ElementValueList As New List(Of ElementValue)

While reader.Read
    Select Case reader.NodeType
        Case XmlNodeType.Comment

        Case XmlNodeType.Element

            Dim temp As New ElementValue
            temp.Name = reader.LocalName
            reader.Read()
            Dim textValue As String = reader.Value
            If textValue.StartsWith(vbLf) Then
                textValue = ""
            End If
            temp.Text = textValue
            ElementValueList.Add(temp)
    End Select
End While
```